# PHP pagination does not work

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have following code to display only 10 records at one page. When I load the page for the first time, first 10 records are displayed well (see screenshot) 
[image: first load]
. But when I click on "Next 10 records", the same URL is not loaded with extra GET parameters using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. 
My address bar shows this instead:

```
http://localhost/PHP/$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?page=$page
```

Here is my complete code;

```
<?php
$con = @mysqli_connect( "localhost:3306", "root", "P@ssw0rd", "world" ) or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
//get total number of records
$query = "SELECT count(ID) FROM city";
$result = mysqli_query ( $con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));
$rec_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$rec_limit = 10; //number of records to display

if( isset($_GET['page']) ){ //when user clicks link
    $page = $_POST['page'] + 1; //page count increment by 1
    $offset = $rec_limit * $page;
}
else{ //user has not yet clicked any link
    $page = 0;
    $offset = 0;
}

//xxxxxxxx  $rec_count is taken from result set
$left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit); //number of records remaining to display

$display_query = "SELECT * FROM city LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
$display_result = mysqli_query ( $con, $display_query) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));

echo "<table>";
echo "<th>ID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Country Code</th> <th>District</th> <th>Population</th>";
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($display_result) ){
    extract($row);
        echo "<tr>
              <td>$ID</td>
              <td>$Name</td>
              <td>$CountryCode</td>
              <td>$District</td>
              <td>$Population</td>
        </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";


if( $page == 0 ){ //user has not yet clicked any link
    echo '<a href="$_SERVER[\'PHP_SELF\']?page=$page"> Next 10 records </a>';
}
else if( $page>0 ){ //user has clicked at least once on link
    $last = $page - 2; //here -2 because, in isset block again increment by 1
    echo '<a href='. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page=$last> Last 10 records </a>';
    echo '<a href='. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page=$page> Next 10 records </a>';
}
else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit ){ //when only records less than 10 remains
    $last = $page - 2;
    echo '<a href='. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page=$last> Last 10 records </a>';
}
```

?>

Comment: Variables aren't interpolated in single quoted strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( $page == 0 ){ //user has not yet clicked any link
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?page='.$page.'"> Next 10 records </a>';
}
```

This will fix your single and double quotes and will echo the values instead of the variables. You have to apply the same logic to all the inputs.
You can also do:

```
if( $page == 0 ){ //user has not yet clicked any link
    echo "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$page\"> Next 10 records </a>';
}
```

Comment: Sir, I tried your first solution. It works well. Thanks. But I have two questions: 1) What is { } in second solution. Why is it used? 2) Can not we refer to a variable inside single quotes? As far as I know, it is possible inside double quotations? I am new to PHP.

Comment: Curly braces are for wrapping array items inside a double quotes enclosed string. To use single quote to wrap strings requires variable concatenation. Double and single quotes behave differently. Note: if the answer fixed the issue please mark it as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo '<a href="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page='.$page.'"> Next 10 records </a>';
```

And similar $last.

Comment: You are missing double quotes around href value

Comment: Double quotes were not the problem here but $variables. But ok, I fixed the double quotes too.

Comment: What is `$variables`? The problem was in the quote but you can't fix one side unfixing the other :)

Comment: I meant $page which was in single quote in php... I fixed it... And double quotes around HREF VALUE were not a problem here. It is just to nice have it, but it was not a problem here.

Comment: The double (double not single) quotes around a html tag attribute (like href) are not a nice to have... Probably the browser will try to fix it autonomously but they are not "just a nice to have". See [here](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) for an example

Comment: I know it should be for correct HTML syntax. But try to read carefully: **it was not a problem here. The problem here was bad quote for $page variable**. Is it so hard to understand that simple fact?